# How to overfit data with Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I'm trying to build a simple regression model using keras and tensorflow. In my problem I have data in the form `(x, y)`, where `x` and `y` are simply numbers. I'd like to build a keras model in order to predict `y` using `x` as an input.

Since I think images better explains thing, these are my data:

[image]

We may discuss if they are good or not, but in my problem I cannot really cheat them.

My keras model is the following (data are splitted 30% test `(X_test, y_test)` and 70% training `(X_train, y_train)`):

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=() activation="relu", name="first_layer"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", name="second_layer"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="output_layer"))

model.compile(loss = "mean_squared_error", optimizer = "adam", metrics=["mse"] )

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=1, verbose=0, shuffle=False) 
eval_result = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print("\n\nTest loss:", eval_result, "\n")

predict_Y = model.predict(X)
```

note: `X` contains both `X_test` and `X_train`.

Plotting the prediction I get (blue squares are the prediction `predict_Y`)

[image]

I'm playing a lot with layers, activation funztions and other parameters. My goal is to find the best parameters to train the model, but the actual question, here, is slightly different: in fact I have hard times to force the model to overfit the data (as you can see from the above results).

Does anyone have some sort of idea about how to reproduce overfitting?

This is the outcome I would like to get:
[image]

(red dots are under blue squares!)

EDIT:

Here I provide you the data used in the example above: you can copy paste directly to a python interpreter:

```
X_train = [0.704619794270697, 0.6779457393024553, 0.8207082120250023, 0.8588819357831449, 0.8692320257603844, 0.6878750931810429, 0.9556331888763945, 0.77677964510883, 0.7211381534179618, 0.6438319113259414, 0.6478339581502052, 0.9710222750072649, 0.8952188423349681, 0.6303124926673513, 0.9640316662124185, 0.869691568491902, 0.8320164648420931, 0.8236399177660375, 0.8877334038470911, 0.8084042532069621, 0.8045680821762038]
y_train = [0.7766424210611557, 0.8210846773655833, 0.9996114311913593, 0.8041331063189883, 0.9980525368790883, 0.8164056182686034, 0.8925487603333683, 0.7758207470960685, 0.37345286573743475, 0.9325789202459493, 0.6060269037514895, 0.9319771743389491, 0.9990691225991941, 0.9320002808310418, 0.9992560731072977, 0.9980241561997089, 0.8882905258641204, 0.4678339275898943, 0.9312152374846061, 0.9542371205095945, 0.8885893668675711]
X_test = [0.9749191829308574, 0.8735366740730178, 0.8882783211709133, 0.8022891400991644, 0.8650601322313454, 0.8697902997857514, 1.0, 0.8165876695985228, 0.8923841531760973]
y_test = [0.975653685270635, 0.9096752789481569, 0.6653736469114154, 0.46367666660348744, 0.9991817903431941, 1.0, 0.9111205717076893, 0.5264993912088891, 0.9989199241685126]
X = [0.704619794270697, 0.77677964510883, 0.7211381534179618, 0.6478339581502052, 0.6779457393024553, 0.8588819357831449, 0.8045680821762038, 0.8320164648420931, 0.8650601322313454, 0.8697902997857514, 0.8236399177660375, 0.6878750931810429, 0.8923841531760973, 0.8692320257603844, 0.8877334038470911, 0.8735366740730178, 0.8207082120250023, 0.8022891400991644, 0.6303124926673513, 0.8084042532069621, 0.869691568491902, 0.9710222750072649, 0.9556331888763945, 0.8882783211709133, 0.8165876695985228, 0.6438319113259414, 0.8952188423349681, 0.9749191829308574, 1.0, 0.9640316662124185]
Y = [0.7766424210611557, 0.7758207470960685, 0.37345286573743475, 0.6060269037514895, 0.8210846773655833, 0.8041331063189883, 0.8885893668675711, 0.8882905258641204, 0.9991817903431941, 1.0, 0.4678339275898943, 0.8164056182686034, 0.9989199241685126, 0.9980525368790883, 0.9312152374846061, 0.9096752789481569, 0.9996114311913593, 0.46367666660348744, 0.9320002808310418, 0.9542371205095945, 0.9980241561997089, 0.9319771743389491, 0.8925487603333683, 0.6653736469114154, 0.5264993912088891, 0.9325789202459493, 0.9990691225991941, 0.975653685270635, 0.9111205717076893, 0.9992560731072977]
```

Where `X` contains the list of the x values and `Y` the corresponding y value. (X_test, y_test) and (X_train, y_train) are two (non overlapping) subset of (X, Y).

To predict and show the model results I simply use matplotlib (imported as plt):

```
predict_Y = model.predict(X)
plt.plot(X, Y, "ro", X, predict_Y, "bs")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hmm... The data does not follow any linear function or any pattern as of such. Thus the predicting power of your model must be nil. Playing with layers will not help you. As you see from the blue squares, they are in a line. This is how the model expects data. If there is indeed some correlation, it would have to be with some other technique. BUt from my observation, I don't think there is any function to map those points...

Comment: I don't think such a function exist too. But I expect that, from an overfitting model, if I try to predict y from the same x used in the training section... i get from the model the same y as well... (question is "how to reproduce overfitting", not "how to make the model work correctly")

Comment: How will overfitting help in that? If you want to accomplish something like that, just make an array to learn all the values and call it. Overfitting is not a way to do that with a model. What do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: It will not help in that, but It will help in answering my question :) (I added the image of the desired results). You said "just make an array to learn all the values and call it". Maybe it's what I'm looking for: can you explain it better, please?

Comment: Could you share some example data so I can try to reproduce myself? In general, if you want to overfit, then you need to make your model overpowered for the data. This data looks pretty noisy, so you will need a relatively large model to memorize it. You can do this easily by increasing the size of each layer or the number of layers, with "more layers" typically giving more power. But please note: you will not be able to predict the held out test data. Overfitting will memorize the training data, but perform increasingly worse on any data it couldn't see and memorize.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of that: I'm NOT trying to make the model work, just studying its behaviour. I read a lot about overfitting, but never managed to reproduce it (in this example). I've modified the question adding, at the end, the data I'm using (the same shown in the images I've posted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overfitted models are rarely useful in real life. It appears to me that OP is well aware of that but wants to see if NNs are indeed capable of fitting (bounded) arbitrary functions or not. On one hand, the input-output data in the example *seems* to obey no discernible pattern. On the other hand, both input and output are scalars in [0, 1] and there are only 21 data points in the training set.

Based on my experiments and results, we can indeed overfit as requested. See the image below.

[image]

Numerical results:

```
           x    y_true    y_pred     error
0   0.704620  0.776642  0.773753 -0.002889
1   0.677946  0.821085  0.819597 -0.001488
2   0.820708  0.999611  0.999813  0.000202
3   0.858882  0.804133  0.805160  0.001026
4   0.869232  0.998053  0.997862 -0.000190
5   0.687875  0.816406  0.814692 -0.001714
6   0.955633  0.892549  0.893117  0.000569
7   0.776780  0.775821  0.779289  0.003469
8   0.721138  0.373453  0.374007  0.000554
9   0.643832  0.932579  0.912565 -0.020014
10  0.647834  0.606027  0.607253  0.001226
11  0.971022  0.931977  0.931549 -0.000428
12  0.895219  0.999069  0.999051 -0.000018
13  0.630312  0.932000  0.930252 -0.001748
14  0.964032  0.999256  0.999204 -0.000052
15  0.869692  0.998024  0.997859 -0.000165
16  0.832016  0.888291  0.887883 -0.000407
17  0.823640  0.467834  0.460728 -0.007106
18  0.887733  0.931215  0.932790  0.001575
19  0.808404  0.954237  0.960282  0.006045
20  0.804568  0.888589  0.906829  0.018240
{'me': -0.00015776709314323828, 
 'mae': 0.00329163070145315, 
 'mse': 4.0713782563067185e-05, 
 'rmse': 0.006380735268216915}
```

OP's code seems good to me. My changes were minor:

1. Use deeper networks. It may not actually be necessary to use a depth of 30 layers but since we just want to overfit, I didn't experiment too much with what's the minimum depth needed.
2. Each Dense layer has 50 units. Again, this may be overkill.
3. Added batch normalization layer every 5th dense layer.
4. Decreased learning rate by half.
5. Ran optimization for longer using the all 21 training examples in a batch.
6. Used MAE as objective function. MSE is good but since we want to overfit, I want to penalize small errors the same way as large errors.
7. Random numbers are more important here because data appears to be arbitrary. Though, you should get similar results if you change random number seed and let the optimizer run long enough. In some cases, optimization does get stuck in a local minima and it would not produce overfitting (as requested by OP).

The code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set seed just to have reproducible results
np.random.seed(84)
tf.random.set_seed(84)

# Load data from the post
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61252785/how-to-overfit-data-with-keras
X_train = np.array([0.704619794270697, 0.6779457393024553, 0.8207082120250023,
                    0.8588819357831449, 0.8692320257603844, 0.6878750931810429,
                    0.9556331888763945, 0.77677964510883, 0.7211381534179618,
                    0.6438319113259414, 0.6478339581502052, 0.9710222750072649,
                    0.8952188423349681, 0.6303124926673513, 0.9640316662124185,
                    0.869691568491902, 0.8320164648420931, 0.8236399177660375,
                    0.8877334038470911, 0.8084042532069621,
                    0.8045680821762038])
Y_train = np.array([0.7766424210611557, 0.8210846773655833, 0.9996114311913593,
                    0.8041331063189883, 0.9980525368790883, 0.8164056182686034,
                    0.8925487603333683, 0.7758207470960685,
                    0.37345286573743475, 0.9325789202459493,
                    0.6060269037514895, 0.9319771743389491, 0.9990691225991941,
                    0.9320002808310418, 0.9992560731072977, 0.9980241561997089,
                    0.8882905258641204, 0.4678339275898943, 0.9312152374846061,
                    0.9542371205095945, 0.8885893668675711])
X_test = np.array([0.9749191829308574, 0.8735366740730178, 0.8882783211709133,
                   0.8022891400991644, 0.8650601322313454, 0.8697902997857514,
                   1.0, 0.8165876695985228, 0.8923841531760973])
Y_test = np.array([0.975653685270635, 0.9096752789481569, 0.6653736469114154,
                   0.46367666660348744, 0.9991817903431941, 1.0,
                   0.9111205717076893, 0.5264993912088891, 0.9989199241685126])
X = np.array([0.704619794270697, 0.77677964510883, 0.7211381534179618,
              0.6478339581502052, 0.6779457393024553, 0.8588819357831449,
              0.8045680821762038, 0.8320164648420931, 0.8650601322313454,
              0.8697902997857514, 0.8236399177660375, 0.6878750931810429,
              0.8923841531760973, 0.8692320257603844, 0.8877334038470911,
              0.8735366740730178, 0.8207082120250023, 0.8022891400991644,
              0.6303124926673513, 0.8084042532069621, 0.869691568491902,
              0.9710222750072649, 0.9556331888763945, 0.8882783211709133,
              0.8165876695985228, 0.6438319113259414, 0.8952188423349681,
              0.9749191829308574, 1.0, 0.9640316662124185])
Y = np.array([0.7766424210611557, 0.7758207470960685, 0.37345286573743475,
              0.6060269037514895, 0.8210846773655833, 0.8041331063189883,
              0.8885893668675711, 0.8882905258641204, 0.9991817903431941, 1.0,
              0.4678339275898943, 0.8164056182686034, 0.9989199241685126,
              0.9980525368790883, 0.9312152374846061, 0.9096752789481569,
              0.9996114311913593, 0.46367666660348744, 0.9320002808310418,
              0.9542371205095945, 0.9980241561997089, 0.9319771743389491,
              0.8925487603333683, 0.6653736469114154, 0.5264993912088891,
              0.9325789202459493, 0.9990691225991941, 0.975653685270635,
              0.9111205717076893, 0.9992560731072977])

# Reshape all data to be of the shape (batch_size, 1)
X_train = X_train.reshape((-1, 1))
Y_train = Y_train.reshape((-1, 1))
X_test = X_test.reshape((-1, 1))
Y_test = Y_test.reshape((-1, 1))
X = X.reshape((-1, 1))
Y = Y.reshape((-1, 1))

# Is data scaled? NNs do well with bounded data.
assert np.all(X_train >= 0) and np.all(X_train <= 1)
assert np.all(Y_train >= 0) and np.all(Y_train <= 1)
assert np.all(X_test >= 0) and np.all(X_test <= 1)
assert np.all(Y_test >= 0) and np.all(Y_test <= 1)
assert np.all(X >= 0) and np.all(X <= 1)
assert np.all(Y >= 0) and np.all(Y <= 1)

# Build a model with variable number of hidden layers.
# We will use Keras functional API.
# https://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2019/06/24/a-guide-to-keras-functional-api/
n_dense_layers = 30  # increase this to get more complicated models

# Define the layers first.
input_tensor = Input(shape=(1,), name='input')
layers = []
for i in range(n_dense_layers):
    layers += [Dense(units=50, activation='relu', name=f'dense_layer_{i}')]
    if (i > 0) & (i % 5 == 0):
        # avg over batches not features
        layers += [BatchNormalization(axis=1)]
sigmoid_layer = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', name='sigmoid_layer')

# Connect the layers using Keras Functional API
mid_layer = input_tensor
for dense_layer in layers:
    mid_layer = dense_layer(mid_layer)
output_tensor = sigmoid_layer(mid_layer)
model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor], outputs=[output_tensor])
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(x=[X_train], y=[Y_train], epochs=40000, batch_size=21)

# Predict on various datasets
Y_train_pred = model.predict(X_train)

# Create a dataframe to inspect results manually
train_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': X_train.reshape((-1)),
    'y_true': Y_train.reshape((-1)),
    'y_pred': Y_train_pred.reshape((-1))
})
train_df['error'] = train_df['y_pred'] - train_df['y_true']
print(train_df)

# A dictionary to store all the errors in one place.
train_errors = {
    'me': np.mean(train_df['error']),
    'mae': np.mean(np.abs(train_df['error'])),
    'mse': np.mean(np.square(train_df['error'])),
    'rmse': np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(train_df['error']))),
}
print(train_errors)

# Make a plot to visualize true vs predicted
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.plot(train_df['x'], train_df['y_true'], 'r.', label='y_true')
plt.plot(train_df['x'], train_df['y_pred'], 'bo', alpha=0.25, label='y_pred')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title(f'Train data. MSE={np.round(train_errors["mse"], 5)}.')
plt.legend()
plt.show(block=False)
plt.savefig('true_vs_pred.png')
```

Comment: That's impressive how you use those two `for` loops to build the network with the Keras functional API. I've never seen that kind of construction before. I was also thinking of creating an extremely deep NN, but I didn't want to cut-and-paste so much. Your approach is very concise.

Comment: Thanks. I love the functional API. I even wrote a blog post on it: https://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2019/06/24/a-guide-to-keras-functional-api/

Answer (score 0):

A problem you may encountering is that you don't have enough training data for the model to be able to fit well. In your example, **you only have 21 training instances, each with only 1 feature**. Broadly speaking with neural network models, you need on the order of 10K or more training instances to produce a decent model.

Consider the following code that generates a noisy sine wave and tries to train a densely-connected feed-forward neural network to fit the data. My model has two linear layers, each with 50 hidden units and a ReLU activation function. The experiments are parameterized with the variable `num_points` which I will increase.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(7)

def generate_data(num_points=100):
    X = np.linspace(0.0 , 2.0 * np.pi, num_points).reshape(-1, 1)
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, num_points).reshape(-1, 1)
    y = 3 * np.sin(X) + noise
    return X, y

def run_experiment(X_train, y_train, X_test, batch_size=64):
    num_points = X_train.shape[0]

    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(50, input_shape=(1, ), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss = "mse", optimizer = "adam", metrics=["mse"] )
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10,
                        batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)

    yhat = model.predict(X_test, batch_size=batch_size)
    plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    plt.plot(X_train, y_train, "ro", markersize=2, label='True')
    plt.plot(X_train, yhat, "bo", markersize=1, label='Predicted')
    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.title('N=%d points' % (num_points))
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Here is how I invoke the code:

```py
num_points = 100
X, y = generate_data(num_points)
run_experiment(X, y, X)
```

Now, if I run the experiment with `num_points = 100`, the model predictions (in blue) do a terrible job at fitting the true noisy sine wave (in red).

[image]

Now, here is `num_points = 1000`:

[image]

Here is `num_points = 10000`:

[image]

And here is `num_points = 100000`:

[image]

As you can see, *for my chosen NN architecture*, adding more training instances allows the neural network to better (over)fit the data.

If you do have a lot of training instances, then if you want to purposefully overfit your data, you can either increase the neural network capacity or reduce regularization. Specifically, you can control the following knobs:

- increase the number of layers
- increase the number of hidden units
- increase the number of features per data instance
- reduce regularization (e.g. by removing dropout layers)
- use a more complex neural network architecture (e.g. transformer blocks instead of RNN)

You may be wondering if neural networks can fit arbitrary data rather than just a noisy sine wave as in my example. Previous research says that, yes, a big enough neural network can fit any data. See:

- Universal approximation theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem
- Zhang 2016, "Understanding deep learning requires rethinking generalization". https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03530

Comment: When using `MLPRegressor` from `sklearn` we could however fit well 100 data points, after normalization. ```from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
reg = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs',hidden_layer_sizes=(2,),
                    activation="logistic",max_iter=10000)
```

Answer (score -1):

As discussed in the comments, you should make a Python array (with NumPy) like this:-

```
Myarray = [[0.65, 1], [0.85, 0.5], ....]
```

Then you would just call those specific parts of the array whom you need to predict. Here the first value is the x-axis value. So you would call it to obtain the corresponding pair stored in `Myarray`

There are many resources to learn these types of things. some of them are ===>

1. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/
2. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGs-Oxne3oAhVlwTgGHfHnDp4QtwIILTAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DQgfUT7i4yrc&usg=AOvVaw3LympYRszIYi6_OijMXH72

Comment: I think this is what I'm already doing: 
"predict_Y = model.predict(X)
note: X contains both X_test and X_train."
When I call the predict method I use the same data that I'm usign for the training (and testing).

Comment: @Gigino To my understanding, you do not need to use a model at all. Why don't you simply follow up on my answer? It would be much useful in future cases when you have more data plus it takes less time to implement (like 2-3 hours for a newbie)

Comment: Because my objective is to implement such a model in a way it behaves "in the wrong way". So, how to build a model that does not behaves correctly (e.g. it overfits the data)? Not using a model at all does not make sense :)